# How to solve recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm

[algorithm img is here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Eqj.jpg)

```
sample(A[], p, r)
{
    if(p=r) return 1;
    sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < n(?); i++)
        sum = sum + A[i];
    int q = (p+r)/2;
    int t = sum + sample(A,p,q) + sample(A, q+1, r);
    return t;
}
```

I use iteration method to solve this question in image.
that code is right?
i can't  make recurrence relation. maybe T(n) = T...? where is "n"

Comment: Use the sum function and do not use it as a variable name.

Comment: You need to use the floor function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are breaking the size of recursion by factor 2, and also have a loop with `n` iteration. Hence, asymptotically, `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n = Theta(n log(n))`.